# Converting Year-Days age format to Integer Form

Tags: r, date

I am working with data from http://www.basketballreference.com relating to individual gamelogs. Each game log has a bunch of data, but specifically I am concerned with Basketball Reference's Age format.

Here is some sample data from Ray Allen's career:

```
Date,Age,Tm,,Opp,,GS,MP,TS%,eFG%,ORB%,DRB%,TRB%,AST%,STL%,BLK%,TOV%,USG%,ORtg,DRtg,GmSc

1996-11-01,21-104,MIL,@,PHI,W(+8),1,28:00,.497,.400,0.0,7.6,3.8,0.0,5.4,0.0,7.1,20.6,111,105,7.4
2,2,

1996-11-02,21-105,MIL,,BOS,W(+22),1,21:00,.795,.800,6.0,9.7,8.1,16.3,7.3,0.0,8.1,26.1,150,98,17.7
```

The "Age" data is listed as Year-Days, such as `21-104` above meaning 21 years, 104 days old.

How can I convert this into integer form (from `21-104` to `21`)?

Thank you so much!

Edit: I am using the **R language**. Sorry for not specifying!

Comment: Programming-Language using?

Comment: (365*years) + days or (1000*years) + days, depending on how you want to be able to parse it out later

Comment: `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(age, 1, 2))` would do it in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your data into a data.frame called `dd`, then it's likely that "Age" was converted to a factor variable. You can strip off the dash-number at the end of the age and convert to numeric. For example

```
dd <- data.frame(Age=c("21-104", "23-63"))
dd$yearAge <- as.numeric(gsub("-.*$","",as.character(dd$Age)))
dd$yearAge
# [1] 21 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to convert year-days into a year.

This will convert to numeric (based on the fractional year):

```
set.seed(1)  # for reproducible example
x <- paste(sample(21:30, 10, replace=T),sample(1:365,10,replace=T),sep="-")
x
as.integer(gsub("\\-.*","",x))+as.integer(gsub(".*\\-","",x))/365
#  [1] 23.20822 24.17808 26.68767 30.38630 23.76986 29.49863 30.71781 27.99452 27.38082 21.77808
```

This will convert with rounding:

```
round(as.integer(gsub("\\-.*","",x))+as.integer(gsub(".*\\-","",x))/365,0)
#  [1] 23 24 27 30 24 29 31 28 27 22
```

If all you want is the years part (e.g. truncate), then assuming none of the players is younger than 10 or older than 99, you can just grab the first two characters and convert to integer:

```
as.integer(substr(x,1,2))
#  [1] 23 24 26 30 23 29 30 27 27 21
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked out quite well both ways.